# Web browser back button should go back to specific page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a file selection menu, the user selects a file and a new page loads the clicked file in a text area. The user edits the text in the text area and clicks a save button.

Then the user should be able to go back to the file selection menu by clicking the web browsers back button.

**The problem:** The web browser requires two clicks on the web browsers back button. It should only require one click.

**Question:**
How can I make the browser go back to the menu by only one click on the web browsers back button?

---

EDIT: I am using sessions:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    if (Session["BrowserBackButton"].ToString() == "true")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("MainMenu.aspx", true);
                    }
}
```

Problem: When I write to the text area and then click browser back button one time it won't load the server side code again, it just removes the previously written text.
Another click and it loads the server again.

Can I load the server on browser back button click?

Comment: Can you paste your code sample here?

Comment: You can't alter the behaviour of the browsers back button. You don't have control of this.

Comment: If you use the URLs wisely you wont have that issue. Maybe the issue is that you insert a page, that you should not do in the first place. And also you can use the History API to manipulate the browser history in a SPA.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the browser go back to the menu by only one click on
>   the web browsers back button?

No you can't. You cannot change browser's behaviour or functionality.

However, you can show a link which goes back to 2 levels in history. Something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-2);">Back</a>
```

Or better still:

```
<a href="./originalPage.aspx">Back</a>
```

Just give a link to the original page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Make the "Save" button fire an AJAX call to do the saving of the edit, instead of a normal Postback. Show the user a 'success' message once the AJAX call is resolved, and then when they hit the Back button, they will go back 1 step to the File Selection page.

Post your existing code if you need a hand with the AJAX. There's a lot of options on how to do it.

Comment: I want the user to be able to click 'save' and then continue writing on the text area, then click 'save' whenever he pleases. But the user should be able to click browser back button whenever and go back to the menu.

Comment: Yep, thats how it would work. They can hit that 'Save' button as many times as they want. Since that button no longer triggers a real postback, the back button will take them back to File Selection, no matter how many times they click 'Save'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessions to check whether the loaded page (from back button) was fired backwards.
Then redirect the page to your desired page.

Something like this...

page 1 > page 2

page 2 onload

```
if (Session["Back"] != null) //if fired backward using the back button
  //redirect to desired page
  //don't forget to set Session["Back"] back to null
```

page 2 > page 3

page 3 onload

```
Session["Back"] = true; //or some key that will determine that you have already reached this page
```

On the first load of page 2 it will be normal since Session["Back"] is empty.
But when you use the back button to return to page 2..Session["Back"] will have a value that will allow you to do anything like a page redirect to page 1.

Comment: Don't do this, it's a hideous hack.